# Всем привет. JavaScript. Тема связана с наследованием. obj.prototype.constructor = obj

Tags: javascript, наследование, prototype

Код взят с сайта https://developer.mozilla.org

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// метод суперкласса
Shape.prototype.move = function (x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info("Фигура переместилась.");
};

// Rectangle — подкласс
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // вызываем конструктор суперкласса
}

// подкласс расширяет суперкласс
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;//**

var rect = new Rectangle();
```

Не совсем понимаю для чего нужна предпоследняя строка, если при создании нового объекта мы все так и так указываем Rectangle в качестве конструктора. Пораспечатывал все что мог в консоли, но не почувствовал разницы между вариантом с предпоследней строкой и без нее.

Comment: со строкой в поле constructor будет Rectangle, без строки - Shape

Answer (score 0):

`prototype.constructor` указывает на объявление `class` с внутренней переменной `this`, указывающей на то, что это - экземпляр `this` с точки зрения `class` (class=this), а потому, собственно, для создания экземпляра class/this нужно делать `new` (новый `что?` экземпляр `чего?` класса `(сущности->this)`)